# .cdr to pdf converion

Tags: coreldraw

hi i am having an problem for converting *.cdr file to *.pdf.. can anyone help me to convert this file.. this file is very much important to me.. thank u..

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Corel Draw file? Do you have Corel Draw? If so, you can use something like [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/index.aspx) to print the file directly to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

In Coral Draw click file --> Publish to PDF

Done

Hope you find the solution